# Organizing files and folders structure

Tags: php, structure, project-management, directory-structure, project-structure

I've been working with web-based solutions for some years now, Mostly PHP and WordPress projects, as this refers to. I'm not quite sure, if I structure my projects in the best way.

**So, how do I structure my project in the right way?**

For example, I have a project where i use Yarn for package control and gulp for my SASS and jQuery. Here my structure looks like this:

- **assets**

  - **css**

    - style.css
    - style.min.css
  - **sass**

    - style.scss
  - **js**

    - scripts.js
    - scripts.min.js
  - **img**
- **node_modules**

  - Bootstrap
  - jQuery
  - And so on
- **root**

  - header.php
  - index.php
  - page.php
  - footer.php
  - gulpfile.js
  - package.json
  - yarn.lock

Isn't there a best practice on this? I can't find any professional page telling about this, and those that do exist, says different things.. There must be some type of guideline, even though everyone is different.

Comment: That's it: there isn't one and definitive only way to do things right and every other way is wrong. For that reason, this question is pretty off-topic in a site like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one result of the research effort scanning every package listed on https://packagist.org detailing which directories are being used by the vast majority of packages, i.e. what most people unconsciously agreed upon without coordination:

https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton

The short summary for directories:

```
If a package has a root-level directory for ...     
                            ... then it MUST be named:
command-line executables    bin/
configuration files         config/
documentation files         docs/
web server files            public/
other resource files        resources/
PHP source code             src/
test code                   tests/
```